# upload videos with caption on youtube in rails 3.x

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am using youtube_it gem for uploading video on youtube.I want to upload videos with caption file on youtube.I am not able to find any method for uploading videos with captions in this gem. Is there any better gem or any other solution for this scenario in rails 3.x with ruby version 1.9.x?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

some one has add this functionality in fork.

https://github.com/nazarhussain/youtube_it